# Types in Scala, Long, Int, etc. 

Tags: scala

Please type this in.

```
scala> 86400000 * 150
res0: Int = 75098112


scala> val i : Long = 86400000 * 150
i: Long = 75098112  


val i  = 86400000 * 150.asInstanceOf[Long]
i: Long = 12960000000

val i  = 86400000 * 150L
i: Long = 12960000000
```

What in the world is going on here?  I've been skydiving and I must say that this is the most dangerous thing I've ever seen.  No compiler check for this?  Obviously if I was substituting 150 for a variable that's different.

## *EDIT*

This was the actual code that got me worried.

```
val oneDay = 86400000
val days150 = oneDay * 150

days150 = 75098112
```

This was not Scala's fault or anyones fault except my own.  Just got me worried.

Comment: Please don't vote this question down.  It's a legitimate question and integer overflow is very dangerous and does cause real problems with real programs.  The fact that it's common across many languages and not just Scala doesn't it make it down-vote worthy.

Comment: When you need really, really big numbers, there's always [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).  It's a little clunky, but it works.

Comment: Voted to close; this is more of a rant than a question. The various examples illustrate that the questioner already knows exactly what is going on: integer overflow.

Comment: Interesting I've never thought of this issue in Java.  I'm very particular about how I define variables in Java though.  Scala's type inference makes me a little less particular(not that this is a type inference problem).  Kind of just changes your programming style.  I guess that can be a good thing though.

Comment: Also trust me, I wasn't trying to rant.  I was more curious than anything.  Sorry for the confusion/problems this has caused.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's nothing Scala-specific about this. It's just a matter of the target type of the assignment being irrelevant to the type in which an operation (multiplication in this case) is performed.

For example, in C#:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int a = unchecked(86400000 * 150);
        long b = unchecked(86400000 * 150);
        long c = 86400000 * (long) 150;
        long d = 86400000 * 150L;
        Console.WriteLine(a); // 75098112
        Console.WriteLine(b); // 75098112
        Console.WriteLine(c); // 12960000000
        Console.WriteLine(d); // 12960000000
    }
}
```

The `unchecked` part here is because the C# compiler is smart enough to realize that the operation overflows, but only because both operands are constants. If either operand had been a variable, it would have been fine without `unchecked`.

Likewise in Java:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int a = 86400000 * 150;
        long b = 86400000 * 150;
        long c = 86400000 * (long) 150;
        long d = 86400000 * 150L;
        System.out.println(a); // 75098112
        System.out.println(b); // 75098112
        System.out.println(c); // 12960000000
        System.out.println(d); // 12960000000
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank for this.  I've just never noticed this issue with Java for some reason.

Comment: Blame C.  Both Scala and C# copied their fixed size integer rules from Java and Java basically copied its rules from C++ which in turn cloned them from C.

Comment: Which in turn got them from FORTRAN, which got them from ASM. Sad.  We're in a profession that didn't exist when my father was born and we are like Talmudic scholars poring over ancient texts.

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious there is no implicit casting going on. `86400000 * 150` is viewed as `int * int` by I imagine the jvm.  It's calculated then assigned to whatever variable type u desire which makes no difference.  So the correct thing to do is make sure at least one of numbers or variables get casted as a long type, `86400000 * 150.toLong` .  The jvm appears to default to the larger type.

Btw, I believe an overflow check on scala's end would only cripple performance.  So the omission of automatic type conversion introduces risk but allows for better performance.  You just have to be careful ..., which should be second nature if you come from a c/c++ backup.